"Pointer may be null when called from function" warning by CLion JetBrain's IDE
I have implemented Stack in C language, but my CLion IDE is suggesting this in line 20 and 28:

Pointer may be null when called from function 'main':20
Pointer may be null when called from function 'main':28

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;
};

int isFull(const struct Stack *s) {
    return s->top == s->size -1;
}

int isEmpty(const struct Stack *s) {
    return s->top < 0;
}

void display(const struct Stack *s) {
    if (!isEmpty(s)) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= s->top; i++) {
            printf("%d Element of Stack is %d\n", i, s->arr[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Stack is Empty\n");
    }
}

void push(struct Stack *s, const int value) {
    if (!isFull(s))
        s->arr[++s->top] = value;
    else
        printf("Stack is Full\n");
}

int main() {
    struct Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    s->size = 5;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));

    push(s, 10);
    display(s);

    free(s->arr);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}


Please identify accurately which lines in the code shown correspond to lines 20 and 28 in the error messages.  As shown, line 20 is the for loop inside display() and line 28 is the function definition line for push().

you never check that malloc() succeeded. So s could be NULL.

You do not verify that the memory allocations in main() succeed.  You could be passing null pointers to your functions as a consequence.  If the first malloc() fails, the subsequent assignment would probably fail and crash your program.  If the second fails, you don't have any checking anywhere and s->arr could be null.

You have a lot of functions that operate on the stack, but not the two most important ones --- one that creates a stack and one that destroys a stack.

Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?
